# How do I force rails to not use a cached result for has_many through relations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, has-many-through

I have the following three models (massively simplified):

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, :through => :bs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end
```

It seems that A.cs gets cached the first time it is used (per object) when I'd really rather it not.

Here's a console session that highlights the problem (the fluff has been edited out)

### First, the way it should work

```
rails console
001 > b = B.create
002 > c = C.new
003 > c.b = b
004 > c.save
005 > a = A.create
006 > a.bs << b
007 > a.cs
=> [#<C id: 1, b_id: 1>]
```

This is indeed as you would expect.  The a.cs is going nicely through the a.bs relation.

### And now for the caching infuriations

```
008 > a2 = A.create
009 > a2.cs
=> []
010 > a2.bs << b
011 > a2.cs
=> []
```

So the first call to a2.cs (resulting in a db query) quite correctly returned no Cs.  The second call, however, shows a distinct lack of Cs even though they jolly well should be there (no db queries occurred).

### And just to test my sanity is not to blame

```
012 > A.find(a2.id).cs
=> [#<C id: 1, b_id: 1>]
```

Again, a db query was performed to get both the A record and the associated C's.

So, back to the question: How do I force rails to not use the cached result?  I could of course resign myself to doing this workaround (as shown in console step 12), but since that would result in an extra two queries when only one is necessary, I'd rather not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I did some more research into this issue. While using `clear_association_cache` was convenient enough, adding it after every operation that invalidated the cache did not feel DRY. I thought Rails should be able to keep track of this. Thankfully, there is a way!

I will use your example models: A (has many B, has many C through B), B (belongs to A, has many C), and C (belongs to B).

We will need to use the `touch: true` option for the `belongs_to` method. This method updates the `updated_at` attribute on the parent model, but more importantly it also triggers an `after_touch` callback. This callback allows to us to automatically clear the association cache for any instance of A whenever a related instance of B or C is modified, created, or destroyed.

First modify the `belongs_to` method calls for B and C, adding `touch:true`

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a, touch: true
  has_many   :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b, touch: true
end
```

Then add an `after_touch` callback to A

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs

  after_touch :clear_association_cache
end
```

Now we can safely hack away, creating all sorts of methods that modify/create/destroy instances of B and C, and the instance of A that they belong to will automatically have its cache up to date without us having to remember to call `clear_association_cache` all over the place.

Depending on how you use model B, you may want to add an `after_touch` callback there as well.

Documentation for `belongs_to` options and ActiveRecord callbacks:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Hope this helps!

#### Newer Rails versions

As @stevenspiel commented this method was made private and then in newer Rails, it was even removed. So you can use either `#reset` or `#reload` the instance (probably you want to reset the association).

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, through: :bs

  after_touch :reset_associations

  private

  def reset_associations
    bs.reset
    cs.reset
  end
end
```

Comment: perfect, just had this exact issue on my app, bye bye ugly javascript solution

Comment: @MattRamirez **Javascript** solution!? WAT? What were you doing?

Comment: `clear_association_cache` was made private in Rails 5 https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d56958 possible alternatives include `reload` and calling `reset` on the association

Comment: For **`belongs_to`** associations, you need to do the following: `self.association( :bs ).reset`.

Answer (score 3):

All of the association methods are built around caching, which keeps the result of the most recent query available for further operations. The cache is even shared across methods. For example:

```
customer.orders                 # retrieves orders from the database
customer.orders.size            # uses the cached copy of orders
customer.orders.empty?          # uses the cached copy of orders
```

But what if you want to reload the cache, because data might have been changed by some other part of the application? Just pass true to the association call:

```
customer.orders                 # retrieves orders from the database
customer.orders.size            # uses the cached copy of orders
customer.orders(true).empty?    # discards the cached copy of orders
                                # and goes back to the database
```

Source http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 2):

(Edit: See Daniel Waltrip's answer, his is far better than mine)

So, after typing all that out and just checking something unrelated, my eyes happened upon section "3.1 Controlling Caching" of Association Basics guide.

I'll be a good boy and share the answer, since I've just spent about eight hours of frustrating fruitless Googling.

> But what if you want to reload the cache, because data might have been
>   changed by some other part of the application? Just pass true to the
>   association call:

```
013 > a2.cs(true)
C Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cs".* FROM "cs" INNER JOIN "bs" ON "cs"."b_id" = "bs"."id" WHERE "bs"."a_id" = 2
=> [#<C id: 1, b_id: 1>]
```

So the moral of the story: RTFM; all of it.

Edit:
So having to put `true` all over the place is probably not such a good thing as the cache would be bypassed even when it doesn't need to be.  The solution proffered in the comments by Daniel Waltrip is much better: use `clear_association_cache`

```
013 > a2.clear_association_cache
014 > a2.cs
C Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cs".* FROM "cs" INNER JOIN "bs" ON "cs"."b_id" = "bs"."id" WHERE "bs"."a_id" = 2
=> [#<C id: 1, b_id: 1>]
```

So now, not only should we RTFM, we should also search the code for `:nodoc:`s!

Comment: Ok, now I'm back to my code to fix it and I'm suddenly not liking it.  Is there a way of marking the cache as stale?  Using the above code, I don't want to have to litter class A with c(true).blahblahblah all over the place.  I'd rather have one function for adding B's and have that mark any cached cs as being stale.

Comment: Would `clear_association_cache` do the trick? I had to put that in a few of my model methods to avoid having stale data in the query cache. Although I feel like even this is not the most elegant solution.

Comment: That is a lot better than my solution.  By clearing the cache I don't have to ensure that the cache is bypassed all over the place.  I do, however still have one slight frustration with it: if A had two associations (say `has_many :ds`), `a2.clear_association_cache` would also blow away the both the cs and ds.  Now, if only clear_association_cache were to take a parameter to invalidate the specified cache, life would be wonderful.

Comment: I found an even better way! I posted it as a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21320872/111635 =)

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to disable query cache. In your model, just add a `default_scope`

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many   :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { } # can be empty too
  belongs_to :b
end
```

Verified it working locally. I found this by looking at **active_record** source code in *active_record/associations/association.rb*:

```
# Returns true if statement cache should be skipped on the association reader.
def skip_statement_cache?
  reflection.scope_chain.any?(&:any?) ||
    scope.eager_loading? ||
    klass.current_scope ||
    klass.default_scopes.any? ||
    reflection.source_reflection.active_record.default_scopes.any?
end
```

Comment: Rails 5 need to have something into the default_scope; I used:
`default_scope { all }`

Answer (score 0):

To clear the cache, use `.reload`

```
author.books                 # retrieves books from the database
author.books.size            # uses the cached copy of books
author.books.empty?          # uses the cached copy of books

author.books                 # retrieves books from the database
author.books.size            # uses the cached copy of books
author.books.reload.empty?   # discards the cached copy of books
                         # and goes back to the database
```

Source: [Controlling caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `extend` option and provide a module to reset the loading before it takes place like so:

```
  # Usage:
  # ---
  #
  # has_many :versions,
  #   ...
  #   extend: UncachedAssociation
  #

  module UncachedAssociation
    def load_target
      @association.reset
      super
    end
  end
```